# GitLab, тест веб страниц приложения docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

Всем, привет! У меня такой вопрос по пайлайну. На стадии теста я хочу протестить полученное приложение, которое собирается docker-compose.yml. И имеет три части:

1. Бэкэнд (80)
2. Фронт (81)
3. Postgresql базу (5432)

В джобе теста я хочу проверить, доступны ли страницы по указанным портам, что мне указывать в качестве hostname в curl запросе?

Job test:

```
testbuild:
  stage: test
  image: docker
  variables:
    CI_PIPELINE_ID: 388186978
  tags:
    - "linux"  
  script: 
    - apk add --no-cache docker-compose
    - apk add curl
    - docker-compose up -d
    - curl **???**
```

Comment: А что если в тесте я хочу докер-композом запустить все три сервиса: front,web,bd. То как мне к ним обращаться внутри одной джобы тест? Что-то вроде 1. curl (front?) 2. curl (back?) 3. psql (bd)

Comment: ага, понял проблему. ну, она решается абсолютно штатными методами. куда вы там наконфигурировали слушать процессы, туда и обращайтесь. указали слушать `localhost:8080` — вот этот адрес и используйте: `$ curl http://localhost:8080`. документация — всё там же: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Это будет работать только, если использовать статический порт. Это не всегда возможно и не всегда желательно. Нежелательно, так как занимается глобальный ресурс - порт на хосте, так же параллельно нельзя запустить два теста (не знаю поддерживает ли такое gitlab).

Comment: @RomanKonoval *так как занимается глобальный ресурс - порт на хосте* — в данном случае в качестве «хоста» выступает запущенный gitlab-ом docker-контейнер. неужели автору и в этом контейнере портов не хватает? ну, тогда тесты можно запускать тоже из контейнеров, запускаемых docker-compose-ом. т.е. вместо `curl ...` — что-нибудь вроде `docker-compose exec ... curl ...`

Comment: За exec совет спасибо!

Comment: Если это запускается в докере, то да - меньше проблем. Но есть и другие причины не создавать зависимость там, где ее можно не создавать. Так эта конфигурация знает (совершенно без надобности) о внутреннем устройстве и распределении портов в compose файле, и изменения в этом нужно делать координировано.

Comment: Вот что я получаю при попытке выполнить команду внутри контейнера в джобе пайплана docker-compose exec front  curl http://front:81/index.html
the input device is not a TTY

Comment: добавьте флаг `-T`: `docker-compose exec -T front curl front:81/index.html`

Comment: Connection refused :(

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна команда `port` из `docker-compose`:

```
  script: 
    - apk add --no-cache docker-compose
    - apk add curl
    - docker-compose up -d
    - curl http://$(docker-compose port front 81)
```

Это если у вас имя сервиса в compose файле `front` и вы хотите получить адрес, на который мапится его внутренний порт 81.

Comment: При локальном запуске docker-compose up -d такой вариант работает, но вот в гитлабе   % Total    % 

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 81 after 6 ms: Connection refused

Comment: Ну у вас сервис мог еще не успеть стартовать, его нужно подождать.